# Ember.js Controller Property Issue

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm building an application in Ember.js and I'm having an issue monitoring a property I'm displaying to the user. When the user logs in I'm querying an API to get the count of the number of message that have a field called "isTrue" and seeing how many have a value of "true".

When the user logs into the system I am grabbing an ID from their cookie in the application controller through the init: function()

This data is then being displayed in the Application Template. Is this the best way to do this? I'm having an issue that when the user clicks on a button to change the record from "isNew" == "true" to "isNew" == "false" the property is not updating correctly. Is this the best way to do this or am I going about it all wrong from an Ember standpoint?

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

    messageCount: null,

    init: function() {

        var test = 0;

        //get the cookie
        //query an API to retrieve a set of records to check if a specific field is marked as true
        //Compute the messageCount based on the number of records that are marked as true and set test equal to the message count. 

        this.set("messageCount", test);

    getMessages: function() {

        //repeat the code from the init function
    }

    actions: {

        markAsRead: function() {
            getMessages();
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: Where does 'isNew' come in to play? When you click the action 'markAsRead'? How does the property (I'm guessing 'messageCount') get updated, only on the client or on the server as well? I guess I just don't see where you are trying to change the records...

Comment: @Hana the 'isNew' is stored on the server and is queried through the API every time a user logs in or they mark a message as read through an action that propagates to the markAsRead function.

Answer (score 0):

Check how they keep track of the number of completed tasks in this simple [To Do List example](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs/js/controllers/todos_controller.js#L42-L44).

You should set you property something like this:

```
messageCount: function () {
    return this.filterProperty('isNew', true).get('length');
}.property('path.to.my.messages.array.@each.isNew'),
```

No need to set it manually now, it will update automatically.

Comment: How would you incorporate this when the property value is stored on a server? Every time a user clicks markAsRead the property 'isNew' for that record is changed to false through an API call and then the records are reread and the property messageCount is updated accordingly.